# mongoose schema enum is not working properly

Tags: node.js, mongoose, model, schema

I was developing `userModel` and in the `userSchema` I have a role of a `users` which is 'admin','user','guide' and 'lead-guide' so I use `enum` property and added them as an array inputs, using 'user' as a default value. When I test the `/signup` route in the postman it only assigns the default value 'user' for whatever value I assign to the 'role' field. Please take a look for the following code snippet and tell me where is the problem is:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const validator = require('validator');
const bycrypt = require('bcryptjs');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'A user must have a name'],
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'A user must have an email'],
    unique: true,
    lowercase: true,
    validate: [validator.isEmail, 'please provide a valid email'], //checking if the email is relevant
  },
  photo: {
    type: String,
  },
  role: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['user', 'guide', 'lead-guide', 'admin'],
    default: 'user',
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please provide a password'],
    minlength: 8,
    select: false, //to hide in the search
  },
  passwordConfirm: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please confirm your password'],
    validate: {
      //this only works for CREATE and SAVE [not on update ]
      validator: function (el) {
        return el === this.password;
      },
      message: 'Password and ConfirmPassword are not the same!',
    },
  },
  passwordChangedAt: Date,
});

//ENCRYPTING PASSWORD
//middlware
userSchema.pre('save', async function (next) {
  //only run this function if password was actually modified
  if (!this.isModified('password')) return next();

  //HASHING password using bcrypt -with cost of 12
  this.password = await bycrypt.hash(this.password, 12);
  //delete confirm password since we do not want is anymore
  this.passwordConfirm = undefined; //since password confirm is a requrired input not a required database

  next();
});

//DECRYPT PASSWORD
//candiadate password =a password filled in the body
//userpassword=a password stored

//Instance method - which is avaliable in all of our documents
userSchema.methods.correctPassword = async function (
  candidatePassword,
  userPassword,
) {
  //return true or false
  return bycrypt.compare(candidatePassword, userPassword);
};

//Changed password checker
userSchema.methods.changedPasswordAfter = function (JWTTimestamp) {
  if (this.passwordChangedAt) {
    //to change it in mili seconds
    const changedTimeStamp = parseInt(
      this.passwordChangedAt.getTime() / 1000,
      10, //base 10 [] To ensure consistent behavior and avoid potential issues, it's good practice to specify the base
    );
    console.log(changedTimeStamp, JWTTimestamp);
    return JWTTimestamp < changedTimeStamp; //which means password changed recently - because as time increases the miliseconds increased
  }
  //false means not changed
  return false;
};
//creating a model
const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

[Postman Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9LMS.png)

Here is what i enter in the body of the request

```js
{
    "name":"Admin10",
    "email":"Admisnl13'24s0@gmail.com",
    "password":"pass1234",
    "passwordConfirm":"pass1234",
    "role":"admin"   
}
```

but the output is

```js
{
    "status": "success",
    "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjY1NWYzMDBjZWJhOTQxMzM2MDA2YjFiNSIsImlhdCI6MTcwMDczNzAzNywiZXhwIjoxNzA4NTEzMDM3fQ.a474i9cMNIkeTkq4wA97PXQzhspfGzGQVc4expRM5mM",
    "data": {
        "user": {
            "role": "user",
            "_id": "655f300ceba941336006b1b5",
            "name": "Admin10",
            "email": "admisnl13'24s0@gmail.com",
            "password": "$2a$12$S8RCXsoAj2K6zZZgvLFXh.z1rrL0WoABnrg6NzUwRx2Dq2RsuqTQG",
            "__v": 0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code that saves the user to the database i.e. the route `api/v1/users/signup` please.

Comment: i actually found the error , it was on the signup function ```exports.signup = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const { name, email, password, passwordConfirm, role } = req.body;
  const newUser = await User.create({
    name,
    email,
    password,
    passwordConfirm,
    role,
  });

  const token = signToken(newUser._id);

  res.status(201).json({
    status: 'success',
    token: token,
    data: {
      user: newUser,
    },
  });
});```

Comment: Glad you fixed it. Someone might have been able to help you debug if you posted the `exports.signup` function but looks like you solved it on your own.

Comment: thank you very much @jQueeny , i will post the needed code snippet for next time questions.